# create list with spectial type - Spyder error "name ' script ' is not defined"

Tags: python

I want to print `>` in the script 0 to test the code, so I coded `script[0][4][2]`. But the system tells me

```
name 'script' is not defined
```

Can't I define it like that?

```
script[0] = ['A','A',['A'],['A'],['A','5','>'],'A']
script[1] = [2,3,[4,4],[2,3],['V','232','='],'G']
print(script[0][4][2])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define list as `[]` and use `append` to add elements to list:

```
script = []

script.append(['A','A',['A'],['A'],['A','5','>'],'A'])
script.append([2,3,[4,4],[2,3],['V','232','='],'G'])

print(script[0][4][2])
# >
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code slightly:

```
script = [['A','A',['A'],['A'],['A','5','>'],'A'], [2,3,[4,4],[2,3],['V','232','='],'G']]

print(script[0][4][2]) #returns >
```

and it works. From next time try to use the "append" member as suggested by @Austin :)